# Many, complex ModelError add

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, modelstate

I'm little bit new in .core mvc programming.

I have many date validations.

e.g.:

```
private void Validations()
{
    if (startDate >= endDate)
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "ErrorMessage");
       return;
    }

    if (startDate < DateTime.Today)
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "ErrorMessage");
       return;
    }

    if (startDate < dateInTheFuture)
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "ErrorMessage");
       return;
    }

    var substracted = startDate.Subtract(endDate);

    if (substracted.Days < MinDays)
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "ErrorMessage");
       return;
    }
    
    // and so on
}
```

Is there any way to make it cleaner or better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Use [validation attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#validation-attributes) to write manual validations less
2. Create [your own validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes) for complex field validation logic
3. Implement [`IValidatableObject` on your model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ivalidatableobject) and move validation code inside model class